# parsing internal links from text in xml file

Tags: java, regex, xml-parsing

I need to get internal links present in text field of Wikinews xml file.

In my case those are coming in two formats

```
[[w:President of the People's Republic of China|President]]
[[People's Republic of China]]
```

I applied these regex patterns

```
internalLinks = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[w:([^|:]+)\\|.*\\]\\]").matcher(internalLinks).replaceAll("##en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$1##");        

internalLinks = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[([^:|]+)\\]\\]").matcher(internalLinks).replaceAll("[[[en.wikinews.org/wiki/$1]]]");



    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(internalLinks);
    while (matcher.find()) 
    {           
            interLinks += matcher.group(1)+",";
    }


    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("##(.*?)##");
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(internalLinks);
    while (matcher1.find()) 
    {           
            interLinks += matcher1.group(1)+",";
    }

    if (interLinks.length() > 0) {
        interLinks = interLinks.substring(0, interLinks.length()-1);
        return interLinks;
    } else return "";
```

Problem is it is just giving me the links matching first pattern and that too only few links, just 3-4 and not all

Here I have provided an excerpt of the text field of a document.

> {{date|November 13, 2004}}
>   {{Brazil}}[[w:Hu Jintao|Hu Jintao]], the [[w:President of the People's Republic of China|President]] of the [[People's Republic of China]] had lunch today with the [[w:President of Brazil|President]] of [[Brazil]], [[w:Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva|Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva]], at the ''Granja do Torto'', the President's country residence in the [[w:Brazilian Federal District|Brazilian Federal District]]. Lunch was a traditional Brazilian [[w:barbecue|barbecue]] with different kinds of meat.
>
> Some Brazilian ministers were present at the event: [[w:Antonio Palocci|Antonio Palocci]] (Economy), [[w:pt:Eduardo Campos|Eduardo Campos]] ([[w:Ministry of Science and Technology (Brazil)|Science and Technology]]), [[w:João Roberto Rodrigues|Roberto Rodrigues]] (Agriculture), [[w:pt:Luiz Fernando Furlan|Luiz Fernando Furlan]] (Development), [[w:Celso Amorim|Celso Amorim]] ([[w:Ministry of
>
> External Relations (Brazil)|Exterior Relations]]), [[w:Dilma Rousseff|Dilma Rousseff]] (Mines and Energy). Also present were [[w:pt:Roger Agnelli|Roger Agnelli]] ([[w:Vale (mining company)|Vale do Rio Doce]] company president) and Eduardo Dutra ([[w:Petrobras|Petrobras]], government oil company, president).
>
> This meeting is part of a new [[w:political economy|political economy]] agreement between Brazil and China where Brazil has recognized mainland China's [[w:socialist market economy|market economy]] status, and China has promised to buy more [[w:economy of Brazil|Brazilian products]].

Comment: Can you provide a link to Wikinews xml file example ?

Comment: Here is the link
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikinews/20131115/

I took enwikinews-20131030-pages-meta-current.xml

Comment: @Alex I have included a snippet of the contents from text field. Please suggest me what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

```
\[\[(?:w:)?.*?\]\]
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Discussion

This regex assumes that the sequence of characters `]]` will not appear between `[[` and `]]`.
I wasn't able for now to find the escape sequence of `]]`.

#### Demo

http://regexr.com?37e51

Answer (score 0):

I've visited the download page, on top its written:

> See [Meta:Data](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) dumps for documentation on the provided data formats.

I guess they offer better parsing approaches then plain regex, check it out...